# Android TabLayout + ViewPager2 change tab without loading all tab in between

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

In my application, I have a `ViewPager2` and a `TabLayout`. The app is composed of 4 tabs. The 3rd one dynamically loads a list fragment.

I have a problem opening the 4th tab, but only when I didn't opened the 3rd one before.
By example, this will crash:

Open app, show 1st tab. Click on 4th tab. => **App will crash** with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080105 (my.package:id/root_frame) for fragment ListFragment{6190d6d (6304bfad-1db2-464d-a524-7e3450243bcc) id=0x7f080105}
```

But if I proceed as following:

Open app, show 1st tab. Click on 3rd tab. Click on 4th tab. => **App won't crash**.

It looks like when I change tab, it "swipe" through all tabs between the current tab and the clicked one, causing fragments to start initialising.

Here's the code of the **3rd fragment**:

```
class ListRootFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_root_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val transaction = fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()

        transaction.replace(R.id.root_frame, ListFragment.newInstance())
        transaction.commit()
    }
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): ListRootFragment {
            val fragment = ListRootFragment()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}
```

My **ListFragment**:

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
   lateinit var globalData: GlobalData
   private lateinit var listView: ListView

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       globalData = (this.activity as ContentActivity).globalData


   }

   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View { // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       val rootView: View =
           inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

       listView = rootView.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.categoriesList)
       val categoriesList = globalData.getCategories()

       val adapter = this.getActivity()?.applicationContext?.let { CategoryAdapter(it, categoriesList) }

       listView.adapter = adapter

       listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
          // ...
       }
       return rootView
   }

   companion object {
       fun newInstance(): ListFragment {
           val fragment = ListFragment()
           val args = Bundle()
           fragment.arguments = args
           return fragment
       }
   }
}
```

Here's the code of my **ViewPagerAdapter**:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

        return when(position){
            0 -> HomeFragment.newInstance()
            1 -> MapViewFragment.newInstance()
            2 -> ListRootFragment.newInstance()
            3 -> MoreFragment.newInstance()
            else -> HomeFragment.newInstance()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return TAB_COUNT
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAB_COUNT = 4
    }
}
```

And the **Activity that contains the view pager**:

```
class ContentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var globalData: GlobalData
    lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
    lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content)


        globalData = applicationContext as GlobalData

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)


        viewPager.setAdapter(createCardAdapter())
        viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
            TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
                when (position) {
                    0 -> tab.text = "Home"
                    1 -> tab.text = "Map"
                    2 -> tab.text = "List"
                    3 -> tab.text = "More"
                    else -> tab.text = "undefined"
                }
            }).attach()

    }

    private fun createCardAdapter(): ViewPagerAdapter? {
        return ViewPagerAdapter(this)
    }


}
```

Is there a way to prevent tabs 2+3 to load when going from 1 to 4 or, if not, how can I prevent this error ?

**EDIT / WORKAROUND:**

Ok so I found a workaround for this bug. Instead of using a combinaison of ViewPager2 and TabLayout, I now use a BottomNavigation for the exact same result, but without the swiping effect.
In my case it works because I only need 4 tabs, but for more complex apps with more tabs, it wouldn't work, so if anyone knows how to fix it...

Answer (score 4):

To disable `smoothScroll`, use another `TabLayoutMediator` constructor:

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, /*autoRefresh=*/ true, /* smoothScroll= */false
            TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
                //...
                }
            }).attach()
```